# Adding INT values in combo box in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

i'm basically trying to add values **1-100** in combo box but i'm unable to do so

```
for i in range(1,100):
    rollno_list = []
    rollno_list.append(i)

combo_roll = QComboBox()
combo_roll.addItems([str(rollno_list)])
```

Comment: Please add some error logs and explain what issue are you facing. This will help users to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a list with a single element that is a string, instead you must convert each element to a string:

```py
combo_roll.addItems([str(e) for e in range(1, 100)])
```

Also in the for-loop you are creating a list in each iteration where you add a new element which is an error.

Comment: oh i see, thanks a lot, i didnt know this since i'm just getting started with Pyqt5. thanks a lot again ☺

Answer (score -1):

You are initialising `rollno_list`  inside the for loop so basically at the end of for loop there is only one number in your list.

```
rollno_list = []
for i in range(1,100):

    rollno_list.append(i)

combo_roll = QComboBox()
combo_roll.addItems([str(rollno_list)])
```

Comment: How many elements does list `[str(rollno_list)]`  have? Well only one and that is clearly what the OP does not want

Comment: yep, it was only displaying '99' in the combobox. thanks a lot!